# php While Loop causing Duplicate results

Tags: php, json, while-loop

For some reason my php while loop is printing out the data twice and I cannot seem to figure why this is. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$json = '[';
$query  = "SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, phone, phone_two, email FROM customers LIMIT 20";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $json .= "{ num: \"{$row['user_id']}\" },{ num: \"{$row['first_name']}\" },{ num: \"{$row['last_name']}\" },{ num: \"{$row['phone']}\" },{ num: \"{$row['phone_two']}\" },{ num: \"{$row['email']}\" },";
}

//Remove the last trailing comma
$json .= substr($json, 0, -1);

$json .= ']';

echo $json;
?>
```

When I echo the results out to the web browser, instead of having 20 customers, I have 40. However, it is the first 20 customers listed twice. I have no clue what could be causing this to happen.

Comment: Why are you doing all of that?  Just build a PHP array in your loop and then use `json_encode`.

Comment: i agree with using the standard json_encode method.  likewise it would be better to use rtrim($json, ',') just in case there isn't a trailing , (like when no users are returned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `.=` for `=`

So, your statement

`$json .= substr($json, 0, -1);`

becomes

`$json = substr($json, 0, -1);`